# ServiceWorker LifeTime & Push Notifications

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, service-worker

i have a question regarding to ServiceWorkers. I know that those Workers may be terminated by the user agent. Will a so terminated ServiceWorker be able to still receive Push Notifications and wake up to them?

If not, are there any information about how long the service is allow to run usually? I'm targeting Chrome on Desktop as well as Chrome Mobile.

I'm curious about how much i can rely on the workers and how much i can integrate them in my further apps.

**Edit:** What i really did not expected: If i go to [this example](https://serviceworke.rs/push-simple_demo.html) and manually stop the Service Worker (should be equal to termination trough user agent) and then submit a push notification, the service worker gets resumed.

Therefore i assume that Push Notifications can wake up a terminated service worker. Is there any limitation?

Answer (score 3):

A terminated service worker is still capable of handling a `push` event. The browser will start up the appropriate service worker when it detects an incoming push notification from the Web Push server (e.g., Google Cloud Messaging). The incoming push message includes registration information, which allows the browser to figure out which specific service worker to start up.

There are some requirements to fulfill in order for the browser to receive the incoming push notification from the Web Push server.

On desktop operating systems, the actual browser process needs to be running. So, for example, if you're a Chrome on OS X user and you quit Chrome, you won't receive *any* push notifications until you start up Chrome again. (At which point, a bunch might all flow in at once.)

On Android, the connection with the Web Push server is handled via the operating system, and Chrome (and I believe Firefox) does not have to be "running" in order to process the incoming notification and start up the correct service worker.